# Navigation components getting back fragment result returns to start destination

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I am using bottom navigationview with navigation components. Here the first menu is the start destination. Whenever I use      `findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<Contact>("contact") ?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { result ->  viewModel.setContact(result) }` to get result from third menu fragments child fragments fragment. Whenever I  `popBackstack()`  the child fragment it returns to the first menu ie the start destination. If  I `popBackstack()` after commenting out the above code it returns normally to the third menu itself. Is there a way to return to the third menu itself after receiving the result from the child fragments fragment.